# What is a less Kludgy way to Conditionally Prepend a "0" to dateTime Elements?

Tags: c#, datetime, padding, date-formatting, prepend

I want my string YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecondMillisecond to be of this format ("0" prepended where necessary):

```
20140227142807
```

...but this:

```
string YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}_{3}{4}{5}", dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);
```

...gives me "2" (instead of "02") for February, etc. such as:

```
2014227142807
```

I can solve it this way:

```
string YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecondMillisecond = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}_{3}{4}{5}{6}", dt.Year, ConditionalZeroForepad(dt.Month), ConditionalZeroForepad(dt.Day), ConditionalZeroForepad(dt.Hour), ConditionalZeroForepad(dt.Minute), ConditionalZeroForepad(dt.Second);

private string ConditionalZeroForepad(string s)
{
   if (s.Length < 2)
   {
       return string.Format("0{1}", s);   
   }
}
```

...but that's 9X Uglier than a Bag of Butts.

What is a more genteel way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think the variable name `YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecondMillisecond` alone is already "9 times uglier than a bag of butts."

Comment: Maybe 8.3 or so, but definitely not 9!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `string.Format` at all - use [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or to just go down to seconds:

```
string text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(Your variable name suggests you want milliseconds, but your sample suggests you don't.)

Note the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to ensure you *always* use the Gregorian calendar, even if the current culture of the thread is one which has a different default calendar. (Obviously if you *want* a different calendar, that's a different matter.)

See [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Yep, you caught me - I want milliseconds, but stripped that out of *some* of the sample code to try to simplify it, as I thought it was Noda Time to show that.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Well clearly I'm not going to discourage you from using Noda Time :) (You can use the exact same code in Noda Time, although I'd encourage you to use a `...Pattern` instead, for clarity.)

Comment: Every time I hear the song "Tulsa Time" now, this happens:
myBrain.Replace("Tulsa", "Noda");

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a string format like:

```
var str = string.Format("{0:D2}", 2);
```

Value of str:  `02`

The `D2` portion tells the formatter to make sure there is at least two digits in the formatted number.  [See this MSDN page for more on Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But providing a date time format to `DateTime.ToString` is a better solution then trying to compose the format you want from the individual parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
string YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecondMillisecond = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Comment: Yes but so does the poster's example code, really the variable name should be corrected :)

Comment: Yup, just noticed that. Have edited my answer to give both forms and commented that the variable name doesn't match the sample...

Answer (score 1):

You could use ToString() with a format parameter such as dt.Month.ToString("D2")